# MySQL - Update with CASE and ELSE

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I'm developing a small MySQL database about driving licenses. I made a random list with 500 registers where I have a type of license (Moto[A],Car[B],Bus[C],Truck[D],Special[E]) and a random expedition date.

Well now I want to poblate a new column with "expiration_date", with a conditional that if the driving type is D or E the expiration date should be 5 years, and 10 the rest.

The syntax I made is

```
UPDATE db.carnets 
SET date_expiration =
CASE WHEN carnet_type = "D" OR carnet_type = "E" THEN DATE_ADD(date_expiration, INTERVAL 5 YEAR)
ELSE DATE_ADD(date_expiration, INTERVAL 10 YEAR)
```

It shows the generic MySQL error on line 4 [Else date_add....]. 
Where is the error?

Thank you.

Comment: You forgot `END CASE` ?

Comment: Voting to close as a typo -- add `end` -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9a146

Comment: Dammit. It's true, I just forgot adding END...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is adding
        end 
at the end of the sentence as @Antonio Madonna and @sgeddes said.

Thank you.